# Should I put simple template rendering inside some kind of promisse/async? (nodejs, express.js)

Tags: node.js, express

Say I have the following code

```
router.get("/new", (req, res) => {
  const article = {};
  article.article_id = "0";
  res.render("author_edit", {article});
});
```

My intuition is that it is performing an IO operation (reading a template file) and therefore it should use some sort of async.

Is it ok not to use async? Is it ok to use async? Which is better for a small standalone app with no load balancer?

Answer (score 1):

The `async` keyword allows you to use the `await` keyword inside a function (and makes the function return a promise as a side-effect).

You aren't using `await` so there is no benefit in adding the `async` keyword.

---

The `render` function probably calls a function, which calls a function, which (etc etc), which reads a file. It almost certainly does that asynchronously. The person who wrote that code made it to it asynchronously. That person is not you.

If you were writing code to read files then it would probably be a good idea to do so asynchronously, but you aren't. Someone else already has.